# chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener is getting complete status twice or more for each page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Here is my Script, which uses onUpdated.addListener to check each url:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {          
 alert(changeInfo.status);
 if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
 if (tab.url.indexOf("in.yahoo.mail") !== -1) {
 alert(tab.url);
 chrome.tabs.update(tabId, { url: "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin" });
  //injectToTab(tab);
  }
 }
});
```

And here is the Manifest code:

```
 {
  "name": "LeoPlugin For Test",
  "version": "1.6",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'",
  "description": "Extension to Automate.",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/eventPage.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "js": ["js/eventPage.js"]
    }
  ],
  "icons":{"48":"images/bob48.png", "128":"images/bob128.png"}, //Define any icon sizes and the files that you want to use with them. 48/128 etc.
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/bob.png",       // What icon do you want to display on the chrome toolbar
    "default_popup": "testwatch.html"       // The page to popup when button clicked.
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*","https://*/*"             // Cross Site Access Requests
  ]

}
```

Anything missing in the above code that can prevent getting 'complete' status more than once. And also here is my HTML code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Leo Chrome Extension</title>

    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Pluginjshelper.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body class="inner_bg">
        <div class="grey-panel">
            <div>
            <div class="user-pic">
                <img src="Images/leo-logo.png" width="70" height="50" />
            </div>
            <h3>
                Leo Extension</h3><input name="ok" type="button" class="btn" id = "button123"  value="OK"/> <!--onclick = "getCPRepGraph()" -->
                <input name="chkEnable" id="chkPluginEnable" type="checkbox" value="" class="check"  /><span class="lbl">Enable</span>
            </div>
            <div class="clear">
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4>
                    <span class="blue">Plugin </span>Credentials</h4>
                <ul class="addpage-form2">
                    <li>
                        <label class="addpage-label">
                            User Name :</label><input name="txtUserName" id="txtUserName" type="text" class="addpage-input2" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label class="addpage-label">
                            Password :</label><input name="txtPassword" id="txtPassword" type="password" class="addpage-input2" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="clear">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--BASIC INFO panel End-->
            <div class="clear">
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: What is you want to stop hapenning? onUpdated event or ?

Comment: It can't be triggered for every iframe, `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` is for tabs not pages. So that occurs only once for each tabs.

Comment: when a new tab is opened, onUpdated listener changes status twice as complete. The condition if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') will be executed twice or more depending on the page. For example, when I open Google home page, it will get complete status twice. My question is how to stop changing complete status more than once or executing the script in the condition only once.

Comment: @VineelGogineni: I just tried now with Google Home Page and also with some other pages which have iframes, it is not happening.

Comment: @Sudarshan: Thanks for your response and glad its working fine for you, but I am still getting 'complete' status more than once, even 'loading' is coming twice. Is it because of Chrome version, I am using Version 23.0.1271.91. or any manifest settings. I am actually running this script from 'background' scripts file

Comment: @Sudarshan: Is there any way, you can inspect my code to check what is missing, if i can post anywhere in the forum. I would be grateful if you can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: @VineelGogineni: Post all the code ex: manifest.json and related html, js files by editing your problem statement, will pick it up from there

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was a known bug in Chrome [Issue 162543](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=162543) which was marked as fixed on 2012-12-05.

**Workaround:** (not needed anymore)

[Make Event Page to Background Page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html#manifest) by changing code from

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["js/eventPage.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
```

to

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["js/eventPage.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
```

and moving ahead by using background pages for development till the fix is delivered.

**Other Points:**

After a look at your manifest.json why does

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["js/eventPage.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "js": ["js/eventPage.js"]
    }
  ],
```

`js/eventPage.js` is made content script as well as background\event script; Having code for [chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated) will not work in [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) at all, please eliminate this code

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support and valuable comments. I implemented 'Solution a', it is working fine and also thanks for pointing my mistake of using addlistener() in content scripts.

Comment: This appears to be broken again on 28.0.1500.71 on OS X, just beware.

Comment: I am also seeing two "complete" type events, but they are slightly different. the second argument, changeInfo, is "complete" for the first event, and undefined for the second. I put my observations up at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=162543