# Injected script execute twice in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is my popup.js where it's included in my popup.html, it will trigger when I click on browser action's icon.

```
chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true
}, function (tabs) {
    var tabId = tabs[0];

    chrome.tabs.update(null, {
        url: 'https://example.com/login.php'
    }, function () {

        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
            if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
                    file: "jquery.js"
                }, function () {
                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
                        file: "setLogin.js"
                    });
                });

            }
        });
    });
```

I have `alert()` within my setLogin.js, but I have no idea why it execute twice. I expect it will only trigger once as I have set my execute script within the `changeInfo.status == 'complete'` block.

Comment: You are adding a listener every time. So every time you run this code, another copy of your listener is added to the functions to execute when `tabs.onUpdated` is fired. Might that be the problem?

Comment: Have you looked through this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641658/chrome-tabs-onupdated-addlistener-is-getting-complete-status-twice-or-more-for-e